# WIX remove DLL from registry if it set it

Tags: dll, wix, windows-installer, wix3.7, wix3.8

I have an MSI installer that registers a DLL. I also want to give the users the option to manually register the same DLL (could be different version). Consider the case where the user first installs the MSI, then manually registers the DLL (using regsvr32). The previous file is overwritten. 
When I uninstall my initial MSI, the overwritten DLL is also removed. Is there a way I can prevent that from happening in case the first DLL has been overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [FileSearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/filesearch.html) element of WiX and, if the DLL with this version is found, set a property accordingly. You could then use this property to decide if the DLL should be unregistered or not.
I guess for checking if the user registered it manually or not you have to save that information during installation, e.g. somewhere in the Registry. You could then also do a [RegistrySearch](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html) for this key.
You probably also have to set the `Permanent`-attribute of the component and then remove it by yourself (depending on the property set above).

Answer (score 0):

You could ship that other Dll in a separate MSI, making sure it's installed to the same location and has the same component guid. That would result in Windows knowing about it being shared, and uninstalling one MSI would not remove the remaining Dll because of that sharing.

Without knowing your exact situation it's hard to know if that will work. If you always ship a higher version than than the one in your current MSI then it will work. If you try to replace that Dll manually with a lower file version then repair will restore the correct higher version from the original MSI, so you're already in potential trouble. The only safe way to maintain files installed with MSI is with another MSI-type update, like a patch, major upgrade etc.